# Insert in same table with different value

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
INSERT INTO list
SELECT * FROM list
WHERE server = '535566701375389706'
```

How could I copy/paste all rows like the above but change the id to a different ID? (using SQLITE)

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

long way

```
create table tmp as
  select * from list 
    where server = '535566701375389706';

update tmp set id = 1234;

insert into list
   select * from tmp;

drop table tmp;
```

Alternatively,

```
insert into list
  select 1234, col1, col2, .. colN 
  from list
```

Comment: This gives me UNIQUE constraint failed: list.id:

Comment: Fixed by setting the id to null in the update, thanks!